# Android FACEBOOK SDK3.0 - Login is working, but how to post automatic message from the APP once login

Tags: android, facebook

I am learning android, and I imported Android SDK3.0, and included as library for the below Andorid Project.

I used the code:  http://www.kpbird.com/2013/03/android-login-using-facebook-sdk-30.html

Please let me know how i can post the message from my app directly once login. ( Basically i want to share the results of my app to Facebook )

I need Login and post the result in to the app

Java Code:

```
package com.kpbird.facebooktest;

import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton.OnErrorListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private String TAG = "MainActivity";
 private TextView lblEmail;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  lblEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblEmail);

  LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
  authButton.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

   @Override
   public void onError(FacebookException error) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Error " + error.getMessage());
   }
  });
  // set permission list, Don't foeget to add email
  authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info","email"));
  // session state call back event
  authButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {

   @Override
   public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

    if (session.isOpened()) {
              Log.i(TAG,"Access Token"+ session.getAccessToken());
              Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                      new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                          @Override
                          public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,Response response) {
                              if (user != null) { 
                               Log.i(TAG,"User ID "+ user.getId());
                               Log.i(TAG,"Email "+ user.asMap().get("email"));
                               lblEmail.setText(user.asMap().get("email").toString());
                              }
                          }
                      });
          }

   }
  });
 }

 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking read permissions to the user. But you are not asking publish permissions. If you want to share you need to ask **publish permissions** and to read facebook user details then you have to use **read permissions**.

Comment: Is it possible to share example